# Regex Negating a couple of characters

Tags: javascript, regex

```
^(((\s*[\$]?[+-]?\d*|(\d{0,3}(,?\d{3})*)(.\d+)?[\$]?)((\d+|(\d+-\d+)))?)|((\s*[\$]?[+-]?\d*|(\d{0,3}(,?\d{3})*)(.\d+)?[\$]?(\t\s*[$]?[+-]?\d*|(\d{0,3}(,?\d{3})*)(.\d+)?[\$]?)*[\n\rx]*)+))$
```

I have created this Regex to validate financial values: e.g.
$ 22,222,222 $33,415,334 333 2d2 3d3  (this is one valid value)

Now I want to not allow just 's', 'S', 'R' and 'r' characters. But if I remove the  `.` (dots), it also disallows spaces and commas. I am almost done with this and don't want to break all my 2 hours effort just for not allowing these 2 characters only.

Comment: Replace `.` with `\W` since you want to match non-word chars at those locations. If you literally do not want to match `s` / `S` and `R` / `r` use `[^sSrR]`

Comment: First, i'd split this abomination of a regex into parts, that are remotely readable, so you can edit it, without getting a headache.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew consider adding your comment as answer. It worked... phew. It was that simple??. Wish someday I would also be regexpert

Comment: I have not thoroughly investigated your regex but I am 99% positive that it can be shortened into something much more readable. If you could supply a listing of valid and invalid values then I am sure that something much much cleaner can be achieved.

Comment: Some low hanging fruit would be to write `\$?` instead of `[\$]?`

Comment: Any luck with my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show many input examples so what about using something like:

```
^(?: *\$ *\d+(?:,\d{3})*)*(?: \d[a-qt-z\d]\d)*$
```

https://regex101.com/r/nHPgnF/1